# Динамический Массив Размера N

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Начал изучать динамические массивы. И передо мной стоит такая задача: Пользователь вводит число N. Убедитесь, что оно больше 1 и меньше 100. В ином случае завершите программу.
Динамически выделите память под массив из N чисел. Заполните его случайными числами. Выведите массив. Найдите сумму максимального и минимального элемента, выведите их.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    int max;
    int min;
    int maxI = 0;
    int minF = 0;
    cout << "Введите размер массива = ";
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 1)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (n > 100)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    int* ptrarray = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ptrarray[i] = int((rand() % 99 + 1));
    cout << "Массив = " << ptrarray <<endl;
    delete[] ptrarray;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять как вывести массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну вы же по всем элементам массива проходили для вычисления - вот тем же способом его и выведите:

```
std::cout << "Массив = ";

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    std::cout << ptrarray[i] << " ";

std::cout << std::endl;
```

**P.S.**

а зачем такая сложность при проверке размера массива?

```
if (n < 1)
{
    exit(0);
}
else if (n > 100)
{
    exit(0);
}
```

почему бы не облегчить?

```
if ((n <= 1) && (n >= 100)) {
    return 0;
}
```

и кстати читайте внимательнее задачу:

> Убедитесь, что оно больше 1 и меньше 100

а у вас было "больше 0 и меньше 101" по сути

**P.P.S.**

а еще зачем вы случайное число ограничиваете каким-то диапазоном? у вас же в задаче такой цели не стояло

```
int((rand() % 99 + 1));
```

используйте просто `rand()` и не надо приводить его к `int`:

```
ptrarray[i] = rand();
```